# Regex Match and Nested Elements

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex code:

```
 <!--\s?BEGIN (\w+) \s?-->(.*?)<!--\s?END \w+\s?-->
```

Which will match

```
<!-- BEGIN some_functional_name -->
     //some stuff here later
<!-- BEGIN some_functional_name -->
```

What I need is to watch out for nested comments and if the names are the same. For example

```
<!-- BEGIN some_functional_name -->
     //some stuff here later
     <!-- BEGIN another_functional_name -->
          //it'll match up to the below end another_functional_name
     <!-- END another_functional_name -->
<!-- END some_functional_name -->
```

As you can see it's nested but the regex will capture the second to last `END` comment which the `BEGIN` and `END` do not match. Is there a method to get inline regex capture groups?

Example:

```
 <!--\s?BEGIN (\w+) \s?-->(.*?)<!--\s?END $1\s?-->
```

Though I'm also clueless on how to handle nesting? Should I use a positive lookaround or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), e.g. '\1'.

```
    <!--\s?BEGIN (\w+) \s?-->(.*?)<!--\s?END \1\s?-->
```

Here is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/hG8aO3/2).