# JS Regex replace everything between and including HTML comments

Tags: javascript, regex, gruntjs, grunt-string-replace

I'm trying to use grunt-string-replace to replace the contents of a file between 2 HTML comments. What I have come up with works fine over a single line but for the life of me, I cannot get it to match where there are multiple lines.

```
<!-- START COMMENT -->This matches<!-- END COMMENT -->

<!-- START COMMENT -->
this
doesn't
match
<!-- END COMMENT -->
```

My regex I have currently is

```
/<!-- START COMMENT -->[\s\S]*?<!-- END COMMENT -->/g
```

I understood that replacing the `.*?` (which worked for a single line) with `[\s\S]*?` would allow a match over multiple lines but I can't seem to get it to work.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Update:
As commenters below mentioned, my regex was fine, it was how I was implementing it with grunt**

```
//This didn't work
.....
options:{
    replacements: [
        {
            pattern: "/<!-- START COMMENT -->[\s\S]*?<!-- END COMMENT -->/g",
            replacement: '<script src="'+minJSDestination+'"></script>'
        }
    ]
}
.....


//This does work
.....
options:{
    replacements: [
        {
            pattern: /<!-- START COMMENT -->([\s\S]*?)<!-- END COMMENT -->/ig,
            replacement: '<script src="'+minJSDestination+'"></script>'
        }
    ]
}
.....
```

Comment: Did you try using the "m" modifier? (With your "g" one.)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tM0oB5/1 seems to work fine

Comment: @Fraser Your code works. Can you please show the code where you actually use this regex?

Comment: This is where I was testing: http://goo.gl/zkb5Ur I will update the post with my solution

Comment: Thanks for the help @vihan1086 I've updated with my solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244336/regex-match-and-nested-elements

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
pattern: "/<!-- START COMMENT -->[\s\S]*?<!-- END COMMENT -->/g",
```

You have quotes around the RegEx. Remove them and it should work fine:

```
pattern: /<!-- START COMMENT -->[\s\S]*?<!-- END COMMENT -->/g,
```

Comment: Thanks for re-pointing out what I had already pointed out in my edit from which you got the code sample :)